# "Fatal error: Class not Found" in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, classnotfound

This is NewEventController.php:

```
namespace Passtuff\RestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Passtuff\RestBundle\Entity\Event;

class NewEventController extends Controller
{   
    public function createAction()
    {
        $event = new Event(); //line 14

        //...
    }

}
```

and this is Event.php

```
namespace Passtuff\RestBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="event")
 */
class Event {
    //...    
}
```

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Passtuff\RestBundle\Entity\Event' not found in /home/mattia/sites/Symfony/src/Passtuff/RestBundle/Controller/NewEventController.php on line 14

Why?

Comment: and what are the file paths?

Comment: The file paths are 
/home/mattia/sites/Symfony/src/Passtuff/RestBundle/Controller/NewEventController.php
and
/home/mattia/sites/Symfony/src/Passtuff/RestBundle/Entity/Event.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the Entity directory had wrong permissions.

Setting those permissions to `775` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try clearing your cache in app/cache and make sure you have added your bundle to kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have already tried deleting the cache, either manually or by cosole. Symfonyprofiler confirms that the bundle is active.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the `PasstuffRestBundle` registered in the `AppKernel.php` file, inside your application directory:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Passtuff\RestBundle\PasstuffRestBundle(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you need to make sure your bundle is in the right directory and follows the right conventions, in this case, [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) conventions:

```
app/
src/
    Passtuff/
        RestBundle/
            PasstuffRestBundle.php
web/
```

For more information, check out the official docs on [best practices for structuring bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The bundle is correctly registered in the AppKernel.php file. Symfonyprofiler confirms that the bundle is active. I created the bundle using 'app/console generate:bundle', and I checked that the directories are right.